# How to render multiple variables in Pyramid template file?

Tags: pyramid

I am a newbie to Pyramid from Ruby on Rails. I want to know how to render multiple values to the template file.

I have searched a lot but not found any answer.

I just want to render 2 variables to view, e.g render `var1` and `var2` to `mytemplate.pt`.

```
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/mytemplate.pt')
def my_view(request):
    return {'var1': 'value1', 'var2': 'value2'}
```

and in the `mytemplate.pt` file:

```
var1 is: ${var1},  var2 is: ${var2}
```

I got errors saying there's no 'var2' available.

p.s.
in Rails it's pretty easy:

```
# in controller: 
def show_multiple_var
  @var1 = 'value1'
  @var2 = 'value2'
end

# in the view file:
<%= @var1 %>, <%= @var2 %>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this:

```
pserve development.ini --reload
```

Then you can just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>,<kbd>F5</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer:  just restart my server! It seems that it won't autoload the changes of the page!

after simply restarted the server, it works fine!

Comment: You can set pserve to reload templates when they change http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/narr/templates.html#automatically-reloading-templates